# Error while trying to use pipe symbol on BQ extract

Tags: batch-file, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, extract

I'm trying to extract some data from BigQuery to Google Storage, using pipe symbol as delimiter, but it doesn't work (it works only if I use semicolon or tab, but in a particular case, for several reasons, I'm forced to use pipe...)

[Batch file]

```
bq extract --destination_format=CSV --compression=GZIP --delimiter-fields=| --print_header=true  %proj%:%dataset%.%table% gs://%bucket%/extract_%table%*.gz
```

[Prompt]
**'--print_header' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

I already tried with --delimiter-fields=\| or --delimiter-fields=^|

Is there a way to use pipe?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try this line exactly as is and let me know please `bq extract --destination_format=CSV --compression=GZIP -F"|"  --quote "" --print_header=true  %proj%:%dataset%.%table% gs://%bucket%/extract_%table%*.gz`

Comment: Hi Gerhard. I tried your suggestion and it returns errors no more, but still doesn't work...I mean that it doesn't take any action

Comment: is your construct working in your variables you've set? I cannot see them as you did not post them.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`--field_delimiter='|'`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_extract) instead:

```
bq extract --destination_format=CSV --compression=GZIP --field_delimiter='|' --print_header=true  %proj%:%dataset%.%table% gs://%bucket%/extract_%table%*.gz
```

Comment: Hi Maxim. I tried what you suggested, but it doesn't work: ''' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Fabio is that the full error you're getting? And are you using the latest Cloud SDK? If not, please update to the latest with [`gcloud components update`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update). The command above worked for me with Cloud SDK version 272.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using **-F"^|"** and now it works!

Thanks everybody!